# How to click 'OK' on an AlertDialog via code?

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I use `showDialog` and `dismissDialog` in activity to display and destroy my dialog. Is there also a way to issue a click command on the currently displayed dialog without keeping a variable referencing the dialog?

For example, I want to press the 'Ok' / positive button of the dialog via code.

Comment: Are you using a builder to set up your dialog?

Comment: @TronicZomB: Yes, I'm using `Builder` and I'm overriding `onCreateDialog` in the `Activity` to set up my dialog.

Comment: Ok, bakriOnFire has a rather good example of what I was actually going to post right before I noticed his answer. That is pretty much what you will want to model your code like.

Comment: @TronicZomB: I think he misunderstood my question. I know how setup a dialog and how to show and dismiss it. My problem is how to trigger a click event on it via code considering that I don't have a reference to the dialog variable.

Comment: Hmm.. ok I think I might be following you... Good luck!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I haven't tested this code but it should work:

```
AlertDialog dialog = ...
dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to keep a reference to the dialog but are in control of its setup, you could extract the on click code into another method:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = ...
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    onPositiveButtonClicked(); 
  }
});
```

and implement `onPositiveButtonClicked()` in your Activity. Instead of programatically clicking the OK button you can call `onPositiveButtonClicked()` and `dismissDialog(id)`. If you need to handle multiple dialogs, have `onPositiveButtonClicked` take an `id` parameter.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Builder and it does not have a `getButton` method. Is there a way to click the 'OK' button without keeping a reference of the actual dialog?

Comment: If you're able to keep a reference to the dialog, the AlertDialog instance is returned by AlertDialog.Builder#show(). Otherwise, is it possible to move the on-click logic to a separate method? Instead of simulating a click you could just execute the on-click code and dismiss the dialog.

Comment: Yes, it returns an `AlertDialog` but I don't like to keep a variable referencing the `AlertDialog`. Is there a way to access the dialog using the `Activity` given that I have the ID of the dialog?

Comment: I understand your question, but I don't know how to do that. The API doesn't seem to make it easy; keep a reference to the dialog might be the cleanest way to go if factoring out the on-click logic and dismissing the dialog is not an option. If you find a nice way to do it please post. I'd be interested to know :)

Comment: I wasn't able to find an easy way to access the currently shown dialog on the Activity. I ended up using your solution to save a reference of the `AlertDialog` and triggering the positive button by using `dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> I want to press the 'Ok' / positive button of the dialog via code

Yes, you can do it by getting instance of `POSITIVE` BUTTON and then call `performClick()` on it. try it as:

```
Button okButton = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
okButton.performClick(); //<<< click Button using code
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if I don't have reference to the ``variable? Is there a way to access the `POSITIVE` button using the `Activity` only (similar to `dismissDialog`)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Builder, it's doesn't have the getButton() function. You can try this one

```
AlertDialog.Builder alBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alBuilder.setMessage("Test Message")
         .setPositiveButton("Yes", null)
         .setNegativeButton("No",null)
alBuilder.setCancelable(false);
AlertDialog alertDialog = alBuilder.show();
```

Then you can access the button by below code

```
alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

```
AlertDialog.Builder alBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alBuilder
                .setMessage("Do you wamt to exit?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                                // Write your code here for Yes
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                                // Write your code here for No
                            }
                        });
        alBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        alBuilder.show();
```

Comment: Thanks! But I think you misunderstood my question.

Comment: I'm looking for something like `activity.getActiveDialog(DIALOG_ID).getButton(...).performClick()`. Just like `activity.dismissDialog(DIALOG_ID)` wherein you can dismiss the dialog by just using the DIALOG_ID.